# unrendered portion for datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So I'm doing a project on Win-forms using c# and i have this DataGridView that's anchored to the each left and right side of the panel. For some reason the right side of the DataGrid is not rendered for some reason.(image in the link below)

If i rescaled my PC resolution when running it will fix the problem
anyone knows why this problem happens?

The datagrid is initialized as such

```
this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.SandyBrown;
this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
 this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(43, 256);
this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1167, 349);
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxMJk.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKxmh.png]

Comment: `dataGridView1.Size` too large?

Comment: I don't think the size being too large matters as if i changed the resolution of windows, the datagridview is rendered properly until the next run

Comment: Do you have another control superimposed? Can you share where you set the width to your columns?

Comment: i simply autosized them as such
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

Comment: you are positioning the grid `this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(43, 256);`, and sizing it `this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1167, 349);` as well as anchoring it. All of that will work for as long as your math does. When I run your code, the grid goes in a weird position and the anchoring makes it that I can't get out of the weird placement and the grid gets cut off. Unless the window is big enough to start with, your code, as-is, does not work.

Comment: but anchoring things to all ends are supposed to stretch the grid right? also it still doesnt explain how the datas in column 4 gets displayed while the grid isnt

Comment: no, `anchoring` is not the same as `docking`

Answer (score 0):

Playing with your code it appears the size of the window, in correlation with the placement and sizing of the gird is to blame. The form window has to be big enough to accommodate the whole grid.

I have fixed your problem locally by adding this line to your Grid initialisation.

```
Size = new Size(dataGridView1.Location.X + dataGridView1.Width + 25, dataGridView1.Height + dataGridView1.Location.Y + 125);
```

Here's my full testcase.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DGVBiggerThanContainer_48112281
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
        BindingList<dgventry> dgvdata = new BindingList<dgventry>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            //comment or uncomment appropriate line to
            //trigger the desired behavior
            FixedInit();
            //origInit();


            Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dgvdata;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dgvdata.Add(new DGVBiggerThanContainer_48112281.dgventry
                {
                    col1 = $"col1row{i}",
                    col2 = $"col2row{i}",
                    col3 = $"col3row{i}",
                    col4 = $"col4row{i}",
                    col5 = $"col5row{i}",
                    col6 = $"col6row{i}"
                });
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// this is your version
        /// </summary>
        private void origInit()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.SandyBrown;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(43, 256);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1167, 349);

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// this is your version with my line added
        /// </summary>
        private void FixedInit()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.SandyBrown;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(43, 256);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1167, 349);

            Size = new Size(dataGridView1.Location.X + dataGridView1.Width + 25, dataGridView1.Height + dataGridView1.Location.Y + 125);
        }
    }


    public class dgventry
    {
        public string col1 { get; set; }
        public string col2 { get; set; }
        public string col3 { get; set; }
        public string col4 { get; set; }
        public string col5 { get; set; }
        public string col6 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Perhaps, docking is what you are after.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DGVBiggerThanContainer_48112281
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
        BindingList<dgventry> dgvdata = new BindingList<dgventry>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            //comment or uncomment appropriate line to
            //trigger the desired behavior
            //FixedInit();
            //origInit();
            //DockingIniti(DockStyle.Bottom);
            DockingIniti(DockStyle.Fill);
            //DockingIniti(DockStyle.Left);
            //DockingIniti(DockStyle.Right);
            //DockingIniti(DockStyle.Right);
            //DockingIniti(DockStyle.Top);



            Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dgvdata;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dgvdata.Add(new DGVBiggerThanContainer_48112281.dgventry
                {
                    col1 = $"col1row{i}",
                    col2 = $"col2row{i}",
                    col3 = $"col3row{i}",
                    col4 = $"col4row{i}",
                    col5 = $"col5row{i}",
                    col6 = $"col6row{i}"
                });
            }

;        }

        private void DockingIniti(DockStyle whereToDock)
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.SandyBrown;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 24;


            dataGridView1.Dock = whereToDock;
            switch (whereToDock)
            {
                case DockStyle.None:
                    break;
                case DockStyle.Top:
                    break;
                case DockStyle.Bottom:
                    break;
                case DockStyle.Left:
                case DockStyle.Right:
                    dataGridView1.Width = 500;
                    break;
                case DockStyle.Fill:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// this is your version
        /// </summary>
        private void origInit()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.SandyBrown;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(43, 256);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1167, 349);

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// this is your version with my line added
        /// </summary>
        private void FixedInit()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.SandyBrown;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(43, 256);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1167, 349);

            Size = new Size(dataGridView1.Location.X + dataGridView1.Width + 25, dataGridView1.Height + dataGridView1.Location.Y + 125);
        }
    }


    public class dgventry
    {
        public string col1 { get; set; }
        public string col2 { get; set; }
        public string col3 { get; set; }
        public string col4 { get; set; }
        public string col5 { get; set; }
        public string col6 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your code although it solves the rendering problem, it wasnt quite right on what im trying to achieve. 
the result of your code result in this image
https://i.imgur.com/J0PgAK6.png

Comment: we have no idea what is it you are trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry the image wasnt pasted

Comment: tell us what you are trying to achieve and we'll likely find a solution.

Comment: for some reason using your test case gives me almost the same problem...
https://imgur.com/a6gCVXy